# Store form in localstorage, retrieve it later for submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, local-storage

In a wordpress website I want that when someone fills a product form (select attributes etc) and clicks buy now, if is not logged in then he is redirected to login form. On succesfull login I want to get the submitted form contents from `localstorage`, fill the form and then submit the form automatically.

Is that possible?

I found that I can store the submitted form like this (but how I can refill the form automatically?):

```
$(document).ready(function()    {  
    $('form').submit(function(e) {    
        e.preventDefault();
        var formFields = $(this).serialize();
        localStorage.setItem('myForm', formFields);    
        //data = localStorage.getItem('myForm');  //retrieve it later
     });
});
```

Comment: Please show your HTML code. They need to be filled automatically and for that we need the code

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to retrieve data from localStorage, get your form fields using DOM selectors and fill their values using the data from localStorage.

In vanilla JS, you can probably do the following:

```
document.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // check if user is logged in according to your usecase
  if(isLoggedIn()) {
    try {
      const formData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myForm'));
      // get input fields. If you have some unique id associated to them, you can use document.querySelector(`#${inputId}`);
      const inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('input');
      for(let i = 0; i<inputFields.length; i++) {
         const inputId = inputFields[i].getAttribute('data-id');
         // fallback to empty string in case it is not found in localStorage object
         inputFields[i].value = formData[inputId] || '';
      }
    } catch(e) {
      // handle error
    }

    // Now you have the form input fields pre-filled, add custom logic from here .. 
  }

})

/* 
  --- Sample DOM ----
  <input data-id="name" />
  <input data-id="city" />


  ---- Form fields saved in localStorage ---
  { name : 'Naruto', city: 'Leaf Village' }
*/
```

Comment: my problem is that I dont want to hardcode the form fields because it can be  different. will that be possible?

Comment: @netdev I believe that is possible, but you still need to identify the input fields to the value that user filled before being redirected to the login page. So I'd say that it'll be good if you have some logic in place to dynamically identify them.

Comment: But I was thinking something like saveing the POST fields in local storage and then (after the login) submit the form with the POST fields retrieved from local storage

Comment: @netdev I imagine your have having multiple input fields. You save the values for them, that's easy. But you'd want to put the values back to correct input fields when user lands back. Question is how do you identify the input fields to the value that user entered? Eg. you have 5 input fields with some value for each. Now we have to map these 5 values back to correct 5 input fields.